# Pass type dynamically to function in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I have two `interfaces` like this

```
interface CatStateProps {
    data: CatState[],
    food: number[]
}

interface DogStateProps {
    data: DogState[],
    food: string[]
}
```

which I am using in a `type` definition

```
type AnimlState= {
    cat?: CatStateProps ,
    dog?: DogStateProps,
};
```

And with that `type` I am creating an object

```
const catsAndDogs: AnimlState = {
    cat: {data: [...], food: [...]}
    dog: {data: [...], food: [...]}
};
```

Now I am accessing `dog`

```
let {dog} = catsAndDogs // dog has the types CatStateProps | DogStateProps
if(dog) {
    let {data} = dog // data has the types CatState[] | DogState[]
    foo(data);
}
```

However, as soon as I pass `data` as a function argument to `foo()`, it becomes of type `any` in the function `foo()`.

```
const foo = (data: ?) => {...}
```

Now, how would I pass the type of `data` to the function `foo()`, **not** doing it like this

```
const foo = (data: CatState[] | DogState[]) => {...}
```

I want to pass the type of `data` in `foo()` dynamically, that when I change `AnimlState` I do not have to add another type to `foo()`.

Comment: I think this defeats the purpose of typescript? You need to explicitly specify the types of arguments the function takes. Curious to see how this can be achieved though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood the question correctly you want your function's parameter to be based on the `AnimlState`

You can achieve it like this:

```js
const foo = (data: Required<AnimlState>[keyof AnimlState]['data']) => { }
             // ^? (parameter) data: CatState[] | DogState[]
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#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-cBtRKJFInTboEui-VK+H5CBmBVCjgUZRhAfkbjufINUeIpPgoQYV0RGgyg2KAaz9W5eWLOB5AuT5a1zdg32Lb9vRZK9sgTHJHgqcoeD4Z9anJXpRggP1MXJYlJghKFmHkGEoFODjbhfXM3ykJZwj2KAAB9tmWMRJCYa1g0ocMURiFi2KpGVsEmDjBKUKBhJLMS1EEVAiVk0IvDSGJK2lPVmVPbILwcAggA)

---

`Required` is used to exclude `undefined` as possible value from
`AnimlState[keyof AnimlState]`, which could also be achieved with

```js
(data: NonNullable<AnimlState[keyof AnimlState]>['data']) => {}
```